# Creating a multirow table entry with a variable number of rows

Tags: tables, macros, multirow

I wish to create a macro that receives a comma-separated list (clist) as an argument and returns a multirow table with the number of rows equal to the number of elements in the list.

I have defined a command \getNumItem that extracts the number of elements in a list. I wish to use the result as an input parameter for the number of rows in the command \multirow. However, this does not work (probably due to some expansion issues).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

    % Extract the number of elements in a clist
    \DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\getNumItem}{m}{%

        \int_new:N \numitem
        \int_set:Nn \numitem {\clist_count:n{#1}}
        \int_use:N \numitem
    }

    % Creates a multirow from a clist
    \NewDocumentCommand{\secondCol}{m}{%

        \tl_gclear_new:N \secondColRows

        \clist_map_inline:nn {#1}{
            \tl_gput_right:Nx \secondColRows {
            & ##1 \exp_not:n {\\}
            }
        }
        \tl_use:N \secondColRows
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Creates a multirow table with a number of rows equal to the length
% of the clist passed as arg #2
\newcommand{\multiRowTable}[2]{%
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        % This is what I would like to have
        % \multirow{\getNumItem{#2}}{*}{#1} \secondCol{#2}  

        % This works
        \multirow{2}{*}{#1} \secondCol{#2}
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \\
    % Verifying that \getNumItem{#2} works on its own
    \getNumItem{#2}
}

% Test
\multiRowTable{a}{b,c}

\end{document}
```

I cannot figure out how to modify \getNumItem{#2} to make this work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your output, there is a simple solution - set a `tabular` with nested `tabular`s for the columns. Since `tabular`s are set by default to be vertically centred, there is no need for the number of rows to use in a `\multirow` setup.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\multiRowTable}[2]{%
  \renewcommand{\do}[1]{##1 \\}%
  \begin{tabular}{ | c | c | }
    \hline
    #1 & %
    \begin{tabular}{ @{} c @{} }
      \docsvlist{#2}
    \end{tabular} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\multiRowTable{a}{b,c}

\multiRowTable{a}{b,c,d}

\multiRowTable{a}{b,c,d,e}

\multiRowTable{a}{b,c,d,e,f}

\end{document}
```

[`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) provides the list processing capability.